# ASUS Laptop Battery Keeps Switching from AC to DC mode

Tags: windows-10, battery

I have an ASUS X450J laptop with Windows 10 and Li-ion battery 15V, 2950mAh, 44Wh. My problem is *whenever I charge the laptop, it keeps switching between "Plugged In" and "On Battery" rapidly*. It sometimes charges the laptop normally, but sometimes it keeps switching from AC to DC mode and the other way around for a couple of minutes, especially when a lot of tasks are running simultaneously (high power consumption).

I don't think it's my charger or battery problem because I've tried replacing both of them but this still happening. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a loose power jack.

Comment: @davidmneedham I don't think it's the power jack problem. This is especially happening whenever some big tasks are running. I guess there's some sort of switches that become active when the battery power consumption is high. I'm not certainly sure if anything like that exists.

Comment: Faulty "electrical" then regardless of it being the receptacle or not—something is obviously affecting the electrical signal telling the laptop it's toggling as fast as you see the switch or whatever. Don't stop at electrical wall receptacle though as the power supply, power adapter, some other type of interference or a short somewhere could cause this too.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is by design. Some laptops will switch to battery once fully charged (even while plugged in) to increase the life of the battery. Then the laptop switches back to "charging" when the battery loses too much juice (maybe 5%) -OR- when the load on the CPU gets too high and wants to draw more power than the battery can deliver.

To verify, try disabling any ASUS Power/Battery software and see how Windows responds.

Comment: I don't use any ASUS Power/Battery software. My laptop keeps switching the charging and plugged in straight away, even when my battery is not fully charged.